# Bash - sort range of lines in file

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, range, lines

Hi fellow overflow users.

I would love to know how to sort a range of lines in a file through a terminal command in Linux.

For example in a `test.sh` file:

```
g++ -o test.out \
Main.cpp \
Framework.cpp \
Sample.cpp \
Blub.cpp \
-std=c++14 -lboost
```

How do I sort from the second line to the second last line (the source file names) in this file.

Desired Output:

```
g++ -o test.out \
Blub.cpp \
Framework.cpp \
Main.cpp \
Sample.cpp \
-std=c++14 -lboost
```

(Sorted from line 2 - 5)

Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With head, GNU sed and tail:

```
(head -n 1 test.sh; sed -n '2,${/\\/p}' test.sh | sort; tail -n 1 test.sh) > test_new.sh
```

Output:

```
g++ -o test.out \
Blub.cpp \
Framework.cpp \
Main.cpp \
Sample.cpp \
-std=c++14 -lboost
```

Comment: But how to send the output into the file. I want this text to be in the file. Do I have to echo it into the file after each command?

Comment: Nice, thank you mate, if I add " && mv test_new.sh test.sh" at the end it even keeps its name.

Comment: Just to mention that you can wrap up all commands using `{ }` instead of `( )` which involve a sub shell....

Comment: Yes, it's possible to replace `( )` by `{ ;}`.

Comment: @DasOhmoffSan Warning: adding `&& mv test_new.sh test.sh` will replace the original file even if there were errors creating the new file. Specifically: if the final `tail` command errored out, it won't do the `mv`; if any of the other commands get errors, it'll go ahead and replace the original file with a probably-damaged replacement. How good are your backups?

Answer (score 7):

Sorting using the `ex` line editor:

```
$ cat file
g++ -o test.out \
Sample.cpp \
Main.cpp \
Framework.cpp \
Blub.cpp \
-std=c++14 -lboost

$ echo 'x' | ex -s -c '2,5!sort' file

$ cat file
g++ -o test.out \
Blub.cpp \
Framework.cpp \
Main.cpp \
Sample.cpp \
-std=c++14 -lboost
```

`ex -s -c '2,5!sort'` will put `ex` in batch mode (with `-s`) and apply the command `2,5!sort` to the input file.  This will sort lines 2 through 5 by executing the external `sort` utility with the lines in the given range and then replacing the same lines with the output of `sort`.

The `echo 'x'` is used to send the `x` command to `ex` which will make it save its modified buffer and exit. Without this, you would have had to manually type `x` at the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit `ex`.

This assumes classic `ex` (as found in BSD). If you have `ex` from a Vim distribution, you may use

```
$ ex -s -c '2,5 sort|x' file
```

This uses the internal sort command in Vim's `ex` (same as `:sort` in Vim).

---

As requested in comments:

To sort all lines from line 2 down to the second to last line in the file using BSD `ex`:

```
$ echo 'x' | ex -s -c '2,$-1!sort' file
```

or, with Vim's `ex`:

```
$ ex -s -c '2,$-1 sort|x' file
```

The range was change from `2,5` to `2,$-1`, i.e., from line 2 to "the end minus one".

---

It's a pity that `sed` doesn't support the same type of operation.

Comment: I like this answer. Thank you +1.

Comment: any ideas on how to dynamically find the `next to last line` (5 in this example) in case the file happens to have more/less than 6 lines?  while something like subtracting 1 from `wc -l` would work, I was wondering if there's anything in `ex` that allows for designating and/or finding the next to last line?

Comment: `ex -s -c '2,5 sort i|x' file` to sort case-insensitive

Answer (score 2):

When you are editing the file in `vi`, and your cursor is at `Blub.cpp`, you can enter

```
:.,+3 !sort
```

Or when you do not want to count the lines, use another range:

```
:.,/std/-1 !sort
```

EDIT: 
From commandline:

```
ex -c'2,5 sort|w|q' test.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I wanted to do this in the terminal as a bash command itself.

Comment: After editing my answer I see that @Kusalananda also found this `ex`. Our answers combined would be `ex -s -c '2,5 sort|x' file`.

Comment: `ex -c'2,5 sort i|w|q' test.sh` to sort case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.awk
{ a[NR]=$0 }
END { 
    print a[1]
    lastline=a[NR]
    delete a[1]
    delete a[NR]
    n=asort(a)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { print a[i] }
    print lastline
}
```

- `a[NR]=$0` : load the file's lines into array `a`; use the line/record number (`NR`) as the array index
- `END { ... }` : once we've loaded all lines into the array, apply the following commands against the array ...
- `print a[1]` : print line 1
- `lastline=a[NR]` : save the last line in our variable `lastline`
- `delete a[#]` : delete the first & last lines from the array
- `n=asort(a)` : sort the remaining lines in our array, assigning the number of array items (aka number of lines left in array) to our variable `n`
- `for/print` : print lines 2 - next-to-last line
- `print lastline` : print the last line

Now run against the sample file:

```
$ awk -f test.awk test.sh
g++ -o test.out \
Blub.cpp \
Framework.cpp \
Main.cpp \
Sample.cpp \
-std=c++14 -lboost
```